# Regex Pattern for Philippine Phone Number

Tags: regex

There are two types of phone number in Philippines.

First Type = it start with `09` followed by `9` numbers. I already did this. This is my pattern for this.

```
^(09)\\d{9}
```

and it is working.

Second Type = it start with `+639` followed by `9` numbers. Example is `+6391571825`. I can't identify the pattern for this because it has special character. What is the pattern for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just escape the special character and place it in alternation as

```
^(09|\+639)\d{9}$
```

- `(09|\+639)` Alternation matches either `09` or `+639`
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string. This ensures that no more digits can appear after the 9 characters.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dY2fA2/1)

Comment: This is my initialization. private static final String Contact_Pattern = "^(09|\+639)\d{9}$"; but it is error saying "Illegal escape character string literal"

Comment: The backslashes need to be double escaped.

Comment: @user3802633 Assuming that you are using java, in java the backslashes must be double escaped in regex strings.

Answer (score 7):

I use this regex: `((^(\+)(\d){12}$)|(^\d{11}$))`

It matches either of the following formats
 1. +639191234567, or
 2. 09191234567

**Explanation**

There are 2 chunks combined in 1 expression. Note that you can hardcode "63" in the expression and change the first chunk like so `(^(\+63)(\d){10}$)`

- `(^(\+)(\d){12}$)` matches the mobile number with area code i.e. +63927...
- `^(\+)` - starts with a +
- `(\d){12}$` - ends with any digit of length 12
- `(^\d{11}$))` matches the number *without* the area code i.e. 0917...
- `\+` - '+' literal
- `\d` - matches a digit from 0 - 9
- `{12}` - matches the length 12
- `^` - starts with
- `$` - ends with

I test my regex here: regex101.com

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently Trying an alternative, since I also need to get the landline/ number:
`^((09|\+639)|(|\d{2}|\d{3}))(-|\s)(\d{9}|\d{7})$`

[enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/dY2fA2/22)

Answer (score 0):

use this for your input pattern or javascript regex or php pregmatch

```
^[+]?[\d]+([\-][\d]+)*\d$
```

> **^** = start string 
>   **[+]?** = + sign first line 
>   **[\d]+** = 0-9 numbers only multiple 
>   **([-][\d]+)*** = 0-9 number but no double - minus sign 
>   **\d** = accept 0-9 multiple numbers 
>   **$** = end of the line

**Philippines (Pinoy) contact number accept mobile and home number REGEX**

add **/gm** on last code if you want to use it on global and multiple line

accept **+** only in first line only

accept **-** only in second line and so on

dont accept double **--**

dont accept double **++**

dont accept **- or +** in last line

[regexcode](https://regex101.com/r/wN1sM3/33)